# Android In-App Billing Database Content - How Do The Purchases Look In The Database

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Does anyone know how the database stores inapp product purchases in various purchase scenarios ? I mean, purchasing an item and then having it refunded. What if the user tries buying the same item again? Would there be 2 lines with "PURCHASED" status in the table and one with "REFUNDED" ? What about the "quantity" column ?

If anyone could share their database from InAppBilling test, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

if the item is unmanaged, i think you are less concerned with REFUNDED and quantity column. If the item is managed, you don't have to worry about the user buying the same item twice because the market app will prevent this from happening. As of the database design, i think it makes more sense to have one row of "REFUNDED" if the user has purchased and refunded the item.

Comment: I was talking about the sample from Google. Since I live in one of those countries where developers can't actually test this thing properly (nor sell applications like 1000 years after Android inception), I need to know exactly what they had in mind.